# What is the meaning of decentralization?

Tags: contract-development, contract-design, decentralization

In persuit to understand blockhain decentralization:

If I am not wrong, it helps prevent control with one entity.

Consider a hypothetical example of a service which takes a string and returns a digitally signed (using its private key) string.

Can this service be decentralized? What is the meaning of decentralization here? Does it mean it can be run by any miner node? But without access to private key, how would they run? Does it mean, such kind of service cannot be decentralized? What is the meaning of decentralization?